# How to change jstree orientation using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I am creating a bilingual form in which I used a jstree. I am going to switch between 2 languages, with different directions. I know that jstree inherits from body's direction. But i want to programmatically changes it's direction.

here is my jstree code:

```
$('#productTree').jstree({
    "core": {
        'data': result.ProductsTree,
        "multiple": true,
        "check_callback": false,
        'themes': {
            'variant': 'large',
            'stripes': true,
            "icons": true,
        }
    },
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false,
        "three_state": false
    },
    "plugins":
        ["checkbox"]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable rtl option in you core options object :

```
$('#productTree').jstree({
    "core": {
        'rtl' : true,
        'data': result.ProductsTree,
        "multiple": true,
        "check_callback": false,
        'themes': {
            'variant': 'large',
            'stripes': true,
            "icons": true,
        }
    },
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false,
        "three_state": false
    },
    "plugins":
        ["checkbox"]
});
```

Comment: dear @mrbm ,This is definition of jstree, How to change it by code withour redifing jstree element?

Comment: To change it without redefining the jstree element use this : 
$('#productTree').jstree(true).settings.core.rtl = true;
$('#productTree').jstree(true).refresh();

Comment: it is not changeing the orientation. whats more refreshing jstree is clearing all check marks.